# Converting these to Java?

Tags: java

I need to convert these to Java:
Ive tried converting line by line for both and when I run it there is no output when it completes

```
 def count_up_from (a,b):
    start = a
    end = b
    count = start
    while count <= end:
        print(count , end = ',')
        count = count + 1
    return count 
  
print(count_up_from(1,5), end = "," "\n")
print(count_up_from(3,6), end = "," "\n")
print(count_up_from(1,2), end = "," "\n")
```

//

```
def count_down_to (a,b):
    start = a
    end = b
    count = start
    while count >= end:
        print(count , end = ',')
        count = count - 1
    return count 
  
print(count_down_to(5,1), end = "," "\n")
print(count_down_to(6,3), end = "," "\n")
print(count_down_to(2,1), end = "," "\n")
```

//

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is very basic python to java. Change format of `count_up_from` to `public static void countUpFrom(int a, int b) {` and call it in the main method. Define integer variables using `int`, change loops and functions to include curly braces, add semicolons, etc. just do a tiny bit of research and you could figure this out.

Comment: Converting line-by-line is seldom the best method (no pun intended).

Answer (score 1):

I did a rough translation here of count_up_from

Your desired outcome is unclear, so its not possible to do perfectly.  This should be enough to help you translate the second.

https://repl.it/repls/CoralOblongSyndrome

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    countUpFrom(1,5);
    System.out.println();
    countUpFrom(3,6);
    System.out.println();
    countUpFrom(1,1);
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void countUpFrom(int a, int b) {
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
      System.out.print(i + ",");
    }
  }
```